# Shopify Batch API Redirects

Tags: shopify

Using POST via an HTTP Client we are having a little trouble adding some redirects to our store via the Shopify API using a Private App we created.

```
https://apikey:password@hostname/admin/redirects.xml
```

We are getting an HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request with the following error:

```
<error>Extra content at the end of the document</error>
```

Have tried entering the sample code from Shopify API: http://api.shopify.com/redirect.xml.html#create

```
POST /admin/redirects.xml HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<redirect>
  <path>/ipod</path>
  <target>/pages/itunes</target>
</redirect>
```

If we do one redirect at a time it is fine if we have more than one then it fails, how do you batch redirects?

Comment: Are there any error returned? Did you set the content type to XML?

Comment: Missed the Content-Type It is now working for Single Instances.... If I try to add more than 1 redirect I get a Bad Request Error <error>Extra content at the end of the document</error>

Answer (score 1):

You can only creat one at a time, you will need to loop over and send a request for each.

Comment: Could anyone shed any light on how you perform this loop?

Comment: You have multiple redirects you want to created, put them in an array in the language of your choice and use a for loop? Not sure how else to explain it.

Comment: Sorry, should have added... not a developer, hiring help on this. Thought it would have been more straight forward as lots of merchants coming over from Volusion etc... will need help with this.

Comment: You could also check out this migration tool: http://www.shopping-cart-migration.com/